# Framework for custom maps

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to develop a journey planning app that will use the customer's own custom created map tiles, custom configuration file, custom coordinate system etc.

My question: Is osmdroid framework suitable for this kind of purpose? If it is, can someone give me a hint about where to start in the framework to create my custom map? And if it's not can you give me some suggestion about where to look for this kind of framework

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you want to create a map with custom style with online tiles - take a look at mapbox.com or install your own mapnik instance. And if you want to create an application with offline rendering and custom styles, take a look at getyourmap.com or OsmAnd

Answer (score 0):

Does "own custom created map tiles" mean that the customer will supply pre-rendered map tiles, e.g. via an own tile server? If so, then osmdroid could be an option for *displaying* the map. But you will still need a router. osmbonuspack allows you to use various online routers.

If you plan to render the maps yourself then take a look at mapsforge. It also provides offline routing for you.

Comment: Yes, the customer will supply pre-rendered map tiles from their own servers, and also configuration file that shows the gives the information about the number of zoom levels, how many tiles in that zoom level,scale etc. So i understand from your comment that Osmdroid can handle this situation, right? Even though the map i want to show has nothing to do with OpenStreetMap.

Comment: Yes. You can even use osmdroid for showing a Google map. Just specify a custom tile provider (also called tile source). See `setTileSource()` and https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToIncludeInYourProject

Comment: The problem for me now is, the customers are not using WGS84 coordinate system for their tiles, so i cannot generate tile urls properly ...

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/15) it should be possible to use a custom projection for osmdroid. However you should create a new question about this if you still have problems.